# Moment.js Get difference between two dates in the dd:hh:mm:ss format?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am calculating the time until 11:59PM of the current day.  Here is an example.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.js"></script>
<script>

    setInterval(function() {

        var now = moment();
        var mid = moment();
        mid = mid.endOf('day');

        var diffHours = mid.diff(now, 'hours');
        var diffMinutes = mid.diff(now, 'minutes');
        var diffSeconds = mid.diff(now, 'seconds');

        console.log(diffHours + "h " + diffMinutes + "m " + diffSeconds + "s");

    }, 1000)

</script>
```

However, I was hoping it would show me a time such as 20h 13m 49s, instead I am getting 20h 1255m 73500s

I understand this is working as intended pretty much, but how can I achieve the format I am seeking?

Comment: You might take a look at [https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) Which should take care that you won't need to mess around with timezones.

Comment: Thanks t.niese, I heard this recommended on another SO answer for a similar problem someone else had.  So will look into it, but for now I think I found a way too do what I wanted fairly easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to modify your `now` variable after each `diff`.

```
var hours = mid.diff(now, 'hours'); //Get hours 'till end of day
now.hours(now.hours() + hours);
var minutes = mid.diff(now, 'minutes');
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I found another way, which uses less lines of code.

`code`
  var now = moment();
  var mid = moment();
  mid = mid.endOf('day');

  var diff = moment.utc(moment(mid,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss"));

Comment: Well obviously it's a matter of how you want your output. With that sample you still have to parse it to separate variables if you want to use it as such.

Comment: Very true Nit.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just for comparison, here's David Stampher's moment.js example from a comment on another answer giving the time until 23:59:59.999 "today" and the same functionality in plain JS:

```js
// Moment.js version
var now = moment();
var mid = moment();
mid = mid.endOf('day');
var diff1 = moment.utc(moment(mid, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss")
             .diff(moment(now, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss")))
           .format("HH:mm:ss");

console.log('moment.js: ' + diff1);

// POJS version
var z = (n) => (n<10? '0' : '') + n;
var ms = new Date().setHours(23,59,59,999) - new Date();
var diff2 = z(ms/3.6e6|0) + ':' +
            z(ms%3.6e6/6e4|0) + ':' +
            z(ms%6e4/1e3|0);

console.log('plain js : ' + diff2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: After almost two years, this worked for me very well :) Thank you RobG